# Divergence of a Tensor Examples?

Tags: reference-request, tensors

Would anyone have a reference to a book where explicit examples of things like taking the [divergence of a tensor](http://astro.berkeley.edu/tac/curvilinear.pdf) (page 4) are given? Stupid computational examples like [the one given here](http://www.maths.bath.ac.uk/~masrs/ma20010/chap2.pdf) (bottom of page 10), thanks!

Comment: A pretty costly book, but see http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/tensor-analysis-with-applications-in-mechanics-leonid-p-lebedev/1101219664?ean=9789814313124.

Comment: Is a numerical example of this kind actually in that book?